# how to copy file to another server with different user account?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my project, when user upload a file in the web page which hosted in serverA, the web page should also copy that to serverB. ServerA and serverB is under the same network which admin can access ServerB file from serverA via network drive(//servername/C$/folderpath).

```
                  string fileName = "my test.txt";
                 string sourcePath = @"C:\myFolder";
                 string targetPath = @"\\vmtest001\C$\myFolder\subFolder";


                 // Use Path class to manipulate file and directory paths.
                 string sourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(sourcePath, fileName);
                 string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);

                 // To copy a folder's contents to a new location:
                 // Create a new target folder, if necessary.
                 if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(targetPath)) //error
                 {
                     System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);
                 }
```

I have tried to copy that file to ServerB and the error message is

> Access to the path '\vmtest001\C$\myFolder\subFolder'is denied.

I see some solutions for that are using a webserivce to move file, could anyone tell me the possibility of that?

Main question: How to copy file between different server?

Comment: You can use [LogonUser](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32.logonuser) function to impersonate other users.

Comment: For me your problem is only an access right in this case. You should give acces to your internet user on the folder. If not, you can install an Filezilla server on your server which contains the folder and use FTP to upload the file.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your web.config:

```
<identity impersonate="true" userName="accountname" password="password" />
```

But this is not recommended. 
You can start a service on ServerA, using FileSystemWatcher to monitor the upload files, copy file to serverB in this service。